# Python call a function every x minutes

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

How to create a timer in python which calls a function every x minutes without letting the entire code wait?

Comment: You need to fix the indenting if you want anyone to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: The indentation of your example code is all over the place. Can you elaborate a bit more about what you mean by "without delaying the complete program"? Are you wanting your counter (it it counting up or down?) to run in a separate thread? Does the rest of the program have a main loop that your counter code could be called from?

Comment: question is unclear. Try adding sample output :\

Comment: It sounds simple, but one way is to redesign around multiple threads, one of which can be dedicated to generating these "timer" events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't be 100% sure what you're trying to ask since your sample code currently has incorrect indentation.

I am assuming you mean something like this:

```
import time
wait = 10
for i in range(wait):
    wait -= 1
    time.sleep(1)
    print(wait)
```

If you simply remove the time.sleep(1), the delay will no-longer occur while counting down. This should work:

```
wait = 10
for i in range(wait):
    wait -= 1
    print(wait)
```

**[Edit]**
Ah, thank you so much for the clarification! I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
import time
while True: # Here is your while loop!
    wait = 10 # Change this to 900 (seconds) to get 15 minutes.
    for i in range(wait+1):
        print(wait)
        wait -= 1
        time.sleep(1) # Delay for one second.

    print("Send email here!")
```

**[Double-edit]**
Oh, you would like to have sending emails not block the main section of your program! What @kenny-ostrom said would be correct here, then, you'd like to use threading in some way. Here's an example of sending an email every 15 minutes or 900 seconds. This happens in the background and whatever the while loop is doing is **NOT** blocked or delayed. This should be what you're looking for. c:

```
import threading, time
def send_my_email():
    while True:
        time.sleep(3) # Every 15 minutes is 900.
        print("Send email now saying: {}".format(email_content))

thread = threading.Thread(target=send_my_email)
thread.start()
# Make a background thread and use the function: send_my_email

while True:
    # Do anything here. No delays will happen.
    for number in range(10, 0, -1):
        print(number)
        email_content = number*3 # You can modify email content here.
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: no it doesn't because there is no time delay, so it all counts in 0.0001 second...  try it yourself

Comment: Ah, you're looking for a countdown every second that goes 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 and repeats?

I've updated my answer for you! c:

Comment: @ Snuggle That doesn't work either...

Comment: @TijmenMeijer Could I please ask for more clarification? How does it not work? What would you like the code to do that it's not currently doing? 

Comment: @ Snuggle I want my while loop to keep running without any time delays, but during this loop, I want to set a timer which doesn't involve my regular loop. Hope you can help me.

Comment: @TijmenMeijer Oh, I see! This makes sense! I have updated my answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this:

```
wait = 10
startTime = time.time()
while wait > 0:
    if time.time()-startTime >= 1:
        startTime = time.time()
        print(wait)
        wait-=1
    #do other things
```