# Is there anyway to update values in a JSON file after a certain interval of time?

Tags: python, json, python-3.6

Let's say I have a json file with multiple values as such:

```
{
    "google":5,
    "apple":4,
    "msft":3,
    "amazon":6
}
```

Is there any way I can update each separate value in the file after a certain interval of time? For example, I can change the Google value from 5 to 6 then 7 and so on each minute.

Comment: Why would this be different for JSON files from any other kind of file? What parts do you already know? Do you know how to write a JSON file _once_? If you do, do you know how to schedule a function to be called every 30 minutes? (If not, did you look for a preexisting Q&A entry describing how to do so?)

Comment: Ideally, the question wouldn't be about what you're trying to accomplish as an overarching goal, but about _where you got stuck_ doing it yourself. What's the narrow, specific technical problem that prevents you from implementing this on your own?

Comment: I guess it really wouldn't matter, but I'm specifically practicing using JSON files and I was wondering how I should proceed. In response to the first comment.

Comment: [call a function every x minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56570474/python-call-a-function-every-x-minutes); [how to write a new dictionary to a json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68262954/how-to-write-a-new-dictionary-to-a-json-file) -- just two of the many relevant preexisting questions with answers. Try something yourself, using those and other existing questions' answers, and then you can ask a more specific question after you get stuck.

Comment: You are right. I should have broken down the problem.

Comment: Additionally to @CharlesDuffy there is also a [asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56729764/python-3-7-asyncio-sleep-and-time-sleep) way to do that, so you won't block your entire script with waiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `time.sleep()` you can do this. `time.sleep()` delays your code for the amount of seconds that you specify, decimals are allowed. If you put it in a different thread, you can execute code whilst this is happening. This is some code for the threaded version, but you can remove threading by just calling `updatedict()`

```
import json
from time import sleep
import threading

values = {
    "google":5,
    "apple":4,
    "msft":3,
    "amazon":6
}
def updatedict():
    while True:
        global values
        #incrementing values
        for value in values:
            values[value] += 1
        #Writing file
        with open("values.json","w+") as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(values))
        #Sleeping 1 minute
        sleep(60)
#Starting new thread
threading.Thread(target=updatedict).start()
#Any code you wish to run at the same time as the above function
```

If you intend to run the script multiple times each incrementing onto what is already there, replace the existing `values` variable assignment with

```
try:
    with open("values.json") as f:
        values = json.load(f)
#If the file is not found, regenerates values
except FileNotFoundError:
    values = {
    "google":5,
    "apple":4,
    "msft":3,
    "amazon":6
}
```